# Ignore symlink but not folder in GIT

Tags: git, symlink, gitignore

I have a folder on our server called "media" in production. On our dev site we link media to a synchronized folder.

The problem is on the dev site GIT want's to remove the media folder and replace it with the symlinked folder.

We don't actually want either item in GIT. The problem is that I can' just add media to the gitignore because there are files like this/path/media and skin/media/this etc

To keep my existing folder only I have this rule in .gitignore

```
!media/.htaccess
```

My ultimate goal would be to exclude anything (including symlinks) from git while leaving an empty media folder in the site root.

Comment: Let's say that the symlink didn't exist.  Is there anything in that folder that you actually wanted in Git?

Comment: I think if I could just keep a place holder under media/.htaccess that would be great

Comment: Would ignoring `/media` be appropriate? That only ignores `media` in the root of the project, not in `some/subdirectory/media`. You could then follow that with your existing (but maybe better to be slightly modified) `!/media/.htaccess`...